# Print Value Based on Iteration and condition

Tags: vba

I Want to Print Values from 1 to 10 or less in blank cells from range(A1:A10)
If we find any non blank cell in range(A1:A10) then we have to skip the cell and print the values without disturbing the series i.e, 1,2,3,A(non Blank Cell),4,5 etc

i tried

```
Dim i As Integer 
For i = 1 To 10
If Sheets("Data").cell("K" & i).Value Is Nothing Then
Sheets("Data").Range("K" & i).Value = i
i = i + 1
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Please add which version of VBA, which version of Excel . Which line you are facing the trouble ? Did you use debug tool, any output on debug.print that shows which line is going wrong ?

Comment: I am using Excel 2007

Answer (score 0):

You would be best using a `For Each` loop and manually incrementing the `i` variable each time you do print a number, using the iterated cells row as the row to print the value of `i` to.

```
Dim i As Integer, c As Range

i = 1
For Each c In Range("A1:A10")
    If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then
        Sheets("Data").Range("K" & c.Row).Value = i
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

> `If Sheets("Data").cell("K" & i).Value Is Nothing Then`

In your question text, you mention that the range is from A1:A10. In the code, you mention "K". Unless it's a typo, that may one of the reasons. In addition, replace the above if condition with :

```
If ((Sheets("Data").cell("K" & i).Value Is Nothing) Or  (Trim(Sheets("Data").cell("K" & i).Value) = "")) Then
```